# Do software engineers in general have no idea about Software Architecture Design?

Tags: architecture, module, abstraction, decomposition

I need some help from the community - I hope StackOverflow covers general architecture questions.

So this is not the first time when co-workers of hundreds-people organizations discuss implementation details of the next 'very complex system', which 'will do everything and make everyone happy' without trying to split things into smaller parts.

When I speak about Abstraction and Decomposition and the necessity of splitting into smaller modules with (preferably) a simple interface - nobody seems to understand and reply literally like "we all know how software is developed" or just ignores what I write.

Am I such a unique person with overweight self-esteem, or does that happen often in Software Organizations?

Comment: no, generally everyone knows how their bits fit together. The only difference is for the 'bricklayers' who simply code what they're told, as you often get in outsourced organisations.

Answer (score 2):

Architecture is handled very differently between organisations. If an architect exists as a job role, they are responsible for variable amounts of detail with more or less responsibility depending on the development lifecycle, organisation structure, or developer experience.

Generally though as a rule I would expect an architect to handle the high level modular composition (not class level, but service/package/container level), and any externally visible APIs, maybe a database schema, and any important security points.  But it very much depends on the context.

And so to answer your question (I think?), yes I would expect developers to understand how to break large components into classes, including the logical relationship between them. I would expect they understand SOLID design principles and probably some design patterns. I wouldn't necessarily expect them to understand how to break requirements into large components - because this may be done by an architect.